# Login not being saved in Mantis via Firefox

Tags: firefox, login

I use Firefox to access the team Mantis site

I enter my login info and check "Save login"

I do stuff in Mantis, then close the tab

When I open a new tab, and navigate to Mantis again by bookmark, I have to re enter my login info.

How can I get it to truly save my login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this use NTLM auth?

If so then you need to enable NTLM passthrough in Firefox:

http://sivel.net/2007/05/firefox-ntlm-sso/

> 1. Open Firefox and type `about:config` in the address bar.
> 2. In the ‘Filter’ field type the following [`network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris)
> 3. Double click the name of the preference that we just searched for
> 4. Enter the URLs of the sites you wish to pass NTLM auth info to in the form of:
>
>    `http://intranet.company.com,http://email.company.lan`
> 5. Notice that you can use a comma separated list in this field.

Comment: This probably works, but when going through the steps to implement it, I discovered it also works to not bookmark the login page :/